# ngTagsInput store new values only after submitting a form

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

Is it possible to disable sending a new tag to the server after adding it to the input and saving it later by pushing a submit button?

my Controller:

```
vm.tags = [];
$scope.loadTags = function (query) {
  return $http.get('api/tags?query=' + query);
};
```

and my input:

```
 <tags-input ng-model="vm.tags" key-property="_id" display-property="title" add-on-enter="true" enable-editing-last-tag="true">
   <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
 </tags-input>
```

Comment: Provide the code you're trying to use to give us some context here.

Comment: added my controller and input field

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's *one* way you **could** do it.

You could define a separate function in the `$scope` that adds the tag to an array but does **not** change the DOM *yet*.

And another `$scope` function for **adding** it to the DOM using the [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) directive.